# Como somar várias linhas de duas tabela em MySQL

Tags: mysql

Já tentei com este código, mas só soma uma linha, se modificar o `where`, da erro ou soma errada, preciso somar cada linha separada.

Preciso somar estes dois campos com várias linhas.

- `km_h_tp` é o campo da tabela `t_trocaprogramadas`
- `km_h_pl` é o campo da tabela `t_planos`

sql:

```
select (select sum(km_h_tp) from t_trocaprogramadas where fkplanos_tp =1) +
(select sum(km_h_pl) from t_planos where idt_plano =1)'Proxima Troca';
```

Comment: Dei uma formatada na sua questão para que ela ficasse mais legível, mas você ainda precisa [edit] e explicar melhor o que quer. Não dá pra saber ao certo o que é para somar com quê, o que você chama de linhas separadas, etc. Melhor seria acrescentar um exemplo de como estão seus dados, e como deve ficar o resultado.

Comment: Poste também a DDL das tabelas para sabermos como as duas tabelas se relacionam.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você precisa editar sua pergunta com mais detalhes de suas tabelas, se que outra forma de fazer isso poderia ser, claro não sei o que você realmente que filtra.

Seria interessante você ver um pouco sobre [INNER JOIN](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp) , [SUM](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_sum.asp) e um pouco de [WHERE](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-where-clause.htm) .

```
select (sum(km_h_tp) +  sum(km_h_pl)) as 'Proxima Troca'
from t_trocaprogramadas tp
join t_planos  p
on p.idt_plano = 1
and fkplanos_tp = 1;
```

Comment: ok valeu amigo com uma pequena modificação funcionou, veja o código......................................................................................................select e.apelido_e, p.descricao_pl, (sum(t.km_h_tp) +  sum(p.km_h_pl)) as 'Proxima Troca'
from t_trocaprogramadas as t inner join t_planos as p on (t.fkplano_tp = p.idt_plano)
inner join t_equipamentos as e on (t.fkequipamento_tp = e.idt_equipamento)
where t.fkequipamento_tp =22 group by p.idt_plano;